# How to check if an interval is discontinued?

Tags: javascript

Suppose that I have a list of interval store in an array:

```
[
 {start: "0", end: "3"}, 
 {start: "4", end: "6"},
 {start: "8", end: "10"}
]
```

as you can see the third interval is discontinued from the second, because it should start from `7` and not by `8`, so the user has created a discontinued interval.

I want check if inside that array there are discontinue intervals.

I wrote the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{
   for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
      if(array[x] !== array[i] && array[x].start - array[i].end != 1)
        {
          throw new Error(Lang.interval_discontinued);
        }
   }
}
```

as you can see I iterate over the array, and then create a nested loop for compare all the other intervals.
The first check is necessary to compare if the array is equal, if yes, it's useless execute the checking.
So my logic is this:

I substract the start value of the `x` iteration with the end value of the `i` iteration but this is not solving the problem, and on the contrary it is creating a nice headache.

Infact if I execute a `console.log(array[x].start , "-" , array[i].end , "=", array[x].start - array[i].end);` I get:

```
0 - 6 = -6
```

so the `0` is part of the start of `x` iteration (nested loop) and `6` is part of `i` iteration (first loop).

Maybe I overlooked it? There are another simple way to handle that stuff?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you simply check each next value of your array to see if end & start mismatch? Is your array supposed to be in the order of the intervals? Is there a limitation that enforces the user to have a new interval of at least +1 in the UI?

Comment: @Icepickle so you suggest to use an ordination on the ui, right? This could be a possible solution I guess

Comment: Well, I was mainly asking questions, cause if the order isn't guaranteed then it should be ordered before checking. Also that you have your intervals as string values isn't really helpful

Comment: ok guys thank y'all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have 1 for loop where you check adjacent values in array. If there is a mismatch, log the message and break the loop.

```js
let array = [{start: "0", end: "3"}, {start: "4", end: "6"},{start: "8", end: "10"}];

for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
   if(array[i].start - array[i-1].end !== 1) {
     console.log("issue");
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: this solution will throw an error: cannot read end of undefined

Comment: No it will not. I am starting with `i =1`

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot that

Comment: @Spartaok - No worries. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to check whether there are gaps between the end of one element and the start of the element that follows it. You don't need nested `for` loops for that. Try this:

```
function isContinuous(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    if (arr[i].end != arr[i+1].start - 1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: on the last iteration this will throw cannot read start of undefined

Comment: Did you copy the for loop correctly, especially this part: `i < arr.length-1`? That error happens if you forget `-1`, or put `<=` instead of `<`

Comment: sorry didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

Just loop it in one go after ordering (so you are sure the start intervals are the smaller ones). My check here is that if it is bigger than 1 it's an error (depending on how the input comes in), if not, it would be an easy change

```js
const intervalArray = [
 {start: "0", end: "3"}, 
 {start: "4", end: "6"},
 {start: "8", end: "10"}
];

function getInvalidIntervals( input ) {
  // order by start first
  const copy = input.slice(0).sort( (a, b) => (+a.start) - (+b.start) );
  const failures = [];
  // check against the ordered next value
  for (let i = 0; i < copy.length - 1; i++) {
    if ( (+copy[i+1].start) - (+copy[i].end) > 1) {
      failures.push( copy[i] );
    }
  }
  return failures;
}

console.log( getInvalidIntervals( intervalArray ) );
```